# Nestjs: notfound error when load static file though the file can be gotten

Tags: nestjs, static-files

I have an NestJS app with static file config:

```
ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
  rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'public'),
  exclude: ['/api/(.*)'],
}),
```

That mean i can get some file with path like: `<root_dir>/public/image.png` via `localhost:3000/image.png`.

When I access the `url`, the image display without error, mean I can get static file in `nestjs` server.

But on terminal, I got this error:

```
[Nest] 34189  - 10/10/2023, 3:21:57 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/khanh/WorkSpace/nestjs/social-nestjs/public/index.html'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/khanh/WorkSpace/nestjs/social-nestjs/public/index.html'
```

How can I fix that?